# Assigning actual numeric value in Tensor objects to a numpy array in Tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to slice a matrix in Tensor object as a numpy matrix and use it in some partial computation.
But the assignment from Tensor object to numpy array does not work as follows.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def assignC():
    C_copy = np.zeros((2,2))
    C = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x), x)
    C_copy[0,0] = C[0,0]
    #C_copy[0,0] = C[0,0].eval() # error saying "You must feed a value for  placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float" at line 17
    print(C_copy[0,0])
    return C_copy

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in range(1):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    print(sess.run(tf.identity(assignC()), feed_dict={x: batch_xs}))
```

This ended up with an error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." at line 7.
Would anyone tell me how to extract the numerical value in Tensor object and assign it into the non-tensorflow objects?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid introducing python / numpy code in your TensorFlow graph.

If you want to slice an array, you can use [`tf.slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#slice).

For instance, if you want to get `C[0, 0]`:

```py
C = tf.constant([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]])
res = tf.slice(C, [0, 0], [1, 1])
```

---

The error you get comes from the fact that `C_copy` is a numpy array of floats, and you try to set `C_copy[0, 0]` to a `tf.Tensor`.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; use `.eval(feed_dict={x:batch_xs})`

You are mixing "concrete Tensors" -- objects that represent actual values, like numpy arrays) with "abstract Tensors" -- objects that represent a particular computation, and must be evaluated before use.

When you do `C[0,0]`, C is an abstract Tensor, and `C[0,0]` gets turned into sequence of `Slice` and `Squeeze` operations needed to get the element out, and I guess numpy thinks it's a sequence. Either way, setting it to an array element wouldn't work because numpy expects concrete values, so it needs to get evaluated first, using `eval` or `session.run`